# Boosting query is not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch, boosting

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "is_active": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "is_job_seeking", "is_active"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this query return me all document which has `is_job_seeking=1`, and `is_active=0` and `is_active=1` and that's fine, now when I want to boost score for document which has `is_active=1` I have add `boosting` like

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "is_active": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "is_job_seeking", "is_active"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "boosting": {
            "positive": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 1
              }
            },
            "negative": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 0
              }
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but this give me results only with `is_active=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "is_active": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "is_job_seeking",
    "is_active"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "boosting": {
            "positive": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 1
              }
            },
            "negative": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 0
              }
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```